# Optional RegExp identification not working in ES6

Tags: javascript, regex, ecmascript-6

As per [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) the below are JavaScript ES6 RegExp:

The `?` matches `optional` character
The `.` matches any single character except line terminators
The `\w` Matches any alphanumeric character
The `*` Matches the preceding item 0 or more times

I'm trying with [this](https://chortle.ccsu.edu/FiniteAutomata/Section07/sect07_18.html) to test the following expressions:

```
"show .* report of (?<day>\w+)"
```

The above, matches the: `show me the report of Monday`
But failed, and did not match the `show report of Monday`

I assume `.*` means zero/null or more characters, but looks it is not working with no character! I tried to use `?` as well but failed.

Any explanation and help pls.

Comment: Note that you are also matching whitespace before and after `.*`. Just remove these whitespaces

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`show .* report` matches show, a space, zero or more characters and another space. `show report of Monday` has single space between the two words. A better solution is this regex:

```
/show (?:.+ )?report of (?<day>\w+)/
```

Or this, except that it matches "show misreport of Monday" as well:

```
/show .*report of (?<day>\w+)/
```

The regex is [explained in this demo](https://regex101.com/r/qr8Mra/1).